# Using Variables as Search parameters in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have recently become stuck in my current coding endeavors.  Here is what I am trying to do: code before this pulls item fulfillment numbers and stores them in an array (`myArray` as shown below)  The `IF#` is not enough to load a record, you need the internal ID, which the search below can find.

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  mySearch = search.create({
    type: 'transaction',
    filters: [
      ['numbertext', 'contains', myArray[i]],
      //I get an unexpected error when trying to plug in the array value, SS only wants a value in quotes.
    ],
    columns: [
      search.createColumn({
        name: 'internalid',
        sort: search.Sort.ASC,
        label: 'Internal ID',
      }),
    ],
  });
  mySearch.run().each(function (result) {
    myResults[i] = result.getValue({
      name: 'internalid',
    });
    return true;
  });
}
```

Is there a way around this?

I am also wondering if there are ways to turn objects into strings using `SuiteScript`.  That can always make my life easier ><

Comment: How did you get your fulfillment numbers? Isn't it possible to get the internal id along with (if not instead of) the fulfillment number? 

You can use JSON.stringify in SuiteScript.

Comment: I was pulling the fulfillment numbers from the sales order, I have discovered that I am also blind.  The ID's were right there >< I am sure though that the above will come in handy for other SS searches, so the JSON.stringify method will come in handy!  Thank you!

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, consider writing an answer and marking it as accepted so other people will know how you solved it in the future.

Comment: It will better if you are going to stringify your object before passing it to the filters. Also, try to debug your script using your developer console , or suitescript debugger so you can better understand what are the values you are passing in the filter parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to essentially do a “any of” to an array of strings when comparing to a text field you will need to use a formula and write it out in oracleSQL.

Here is a rough example

“case when {" + customNameField + "} in ('" + splicedNames.join("','") + "') then 1 else 0 end";          
            var filter = search.createFilter({
                name: 'formulanumeric',
                operator: search.Operator.EQUALTO,
                formula : formula,
                values : 1
            });